# Sending variables from jQuery to FPDF

Tags: php, jquery, pdf-generation, fpdf

I'm trying to send the contents of a form with jQuery to FPDF. The variables aren't showing but the pdf isn't giving an error either; it's just blank. I have only one variable so far for brevity. Any guesses?

Form

```
    <form id="contact">
<input type="hidden" name="front_finish_name_field" id="front_finish_name_field" value="Mirror" />
<input type="hidden" name="front_finish_price_field" id="front_finish_price_field" value="15" />
<input type="hidden" name="front_pattern_name_field" id="front_pattern_name_field" value="Tiger" />
<input type="hidden" name="front_pattern_price_field" id="front_pattern_price_field" value="5" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="back_finish_name_field" id="back_finish_name_field" value="Mirror" />
<input type="hidden" name="back_finish_price_field" id="back_finish_price_field" value="15" />
<input type="hidden" name="back_pattern_name_field" id="back_pattern_name_field" value="Tiger" />
<input type="hidden" name="back_pattern_price_field" id="back_pattern_price_field" value="5" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="glass_total" id="glass_total" value="40" />
<br />
<h2>Send Quote</h2><br />
Select agent: <select name="agents" id="agents">
    <option value="1">Jill Smith</option>
    <option value="2">John Smith</option>
    <option value="3">Jack Smith</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

jQuery

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#submit").click(function(){
            var data = $("#contact").serialize();
                $.ajax
                    ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "generate_pdf.php",
                    data: data,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function()
                        {
                            alert("Thank you");
                        }
                    });
                return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

FPDF php

```
    <?php
require('fpdf.php');

$front_finish_name_field = $_POST['front_finish_name_field'];
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,$front_finish_name_field);
$pdf->Output( "sample.pdf", "I" );
?>
```

**EDIT**

It looks like the problem lies in returning the generated pdf to the user. If I set the pdf to be saved on the server, the field values show up in the document.

Comment: Can you disable the PDF generation for a moment and output a `print_r($_POST)` instead? That would show all actual data of the post request.

Comment: Did you mean what it's sending? If so, I've updated the OP.

Comment: That's not the output of `print_r($_POST)`, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean or how to get that information.

Comment: That's the PHP-side, the PHP script. place it below the line `require('fpdf.php');`, write: `print_r($_POST); die;`

Comment: When I put that in and run the file I get only this: `Array ( )`

Comment: That means that no data is passed to PHP. So the problem is not with the PHP script. I think there's something with the jquery.

Comment: I'm starting to think that the information might be getting passed but I'm just not accessing the completed pdf in the right way. The FPDF docs just say to go to your file (in my case generate_pdf.php) and you can accesses it but, if I'm doing that how would my variables still be there? When I go to sample.pdf, it cannot be found.

Comment: Furthermost ensure the data get's acutally passed into the PHP script. `$_POST` is empty, no data at all get's passed. As long as the debug code is in, you won't get any PDF at all.

Comment: I was right about the pdf not getting saved anywhere that I could access it with the browser. When I change the last line to `$pdf->Output( "sample.pdf", "f" );` which saves the generated pdf on the server, it works and the field values are displayed. So, any ideas on returning the generated pdf to the user?

Comment: Sorry, no, I'm not firm with fpdf. Check their API documentation, `->Output` sounds like the right routine for that, *BUT* if it get's generated by an ajax response, your javascript must present the PDF data to your user. The browser is not taking care of that as it's a javascript thing. Dirty Solution: Encode the response data as a [`data-uri`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) then set location to that. Quick and Dirty.

Answer (score 0):

Is the PDF output being generated a valid PDF? If you are accidentally writing whitespace before the PDF preamble the file may show up as blank (because the reader doesn't see the PDF magic characters as the very first thing).

I would very very carefully check the PHP file and make sure the very first characters in the file are `<php` or `<?`, that there is absolutely NO whitespace (new lines, tabs, spaces) before that and that there is absolutely no whitespace after you output the PDF data (try putting an `exit();` afterwards).

Comment: Just confirmed, no white space.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not a very good idea to paste PDF contents into SO like that, but it did show me something important:

The only font in that file is "Helvetica", not "Arial"... Whoops.  According to the FPDF docs, Arial is just a synonym for Helvetica as far as they're concerned.  And it is "Helvetica-Bold".  Okay. So your SetFont call wasn't simply ignored.  That's good news.

And the compressed length of the page's content stream is long enough to make me think SOMETHING is in there, possibly your text (drawn in a way you cannot see).

Can you give us a link to the PDF?  There are any number of reasons why apparently-valid text isn't visible.

Comment: All I get is a blank page.  Saving that "blank page" (in FF4) gave me some html with an empty body.  Just remember that PDF files are a binary format, and must be treated as such.

Comment: See my edit. It turns out everything was working correctly, but it's not returning anything to the user. If I set FPDF to save what the form submits to the server, that pdf has the correctly populated fields.

Comment: That doesn't work either. I think I'm just going to change variables to GET and just generate a url with a query string forgoing the ajax submit. That works just fine and I'm not going to have more than 10 variables so it isn't slow.